# Overriding a methods internal behavior

Tags: java, design-patterns

There is a class `A` that implements a method `doBlah`. I have a class `B` that subclasses `A` and has an `@Override` method `doBlah`. After I perform some simple manipulation in `B.doBlah`, I call `A.doBlah`.

`A.doBlah` calls a static method `C.aStaticMethod`.

A and C are part of an external library I can't modify.

Id like to have a static method `CC.aStaticMethod` called by `A.doBlah` in place of `C.aStaticMethod`. Would this be possible using any design patterns/hacks?

[EDIT]
I do have the source to `A` and I can include files from them into my code and modify etc if required. However, I cant modify the `A` package as such.

Comment: @greedybuddha what class?

Comment: @greedybuddha: These are *static* methods. So no, that won't work. If `A.doBlah` has been compiled to call `C.aStaticMethod`, then nothing will change that.

Comment: @sircapsalot so you're suggesting that he basically rewrites the class A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't modify `A` or `C`, and call `A` directly, the answer is **no**.

If, on the other hand, you don't *need* to call `A.doBlah` directly, you can override it's behavior (provided the method is not `final`), in your own class, and have it call `CC.aStaticMethod`.

If you do have access to the source, you can do a very, very ugly hack:

Create a class `A` in exactly the same package as the original, and modify the method `doBlah` to call what you need.

Keep in mind that this has quite a few drawbacks, namely, if `A` belongs to an external library, you have NO way of knowing if an update to that library will break your code or not, since you'll be running an older version of `A`. 
This is basically to say that this approach can turn quickly into a maintenance nightmare.