# Overriding Default Behavior of a Go struct Method

Tags: go, methods, overriding

Basically asking the same things of [Overriding a methods internal behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613914/overriding-a-methods-internal-behavior) for Go.

I have

```golang
func (f *Foo) String() string {
    return "Foo to string"
}

type Bar struct {
    *Foo
}

func (b *Bar) String() string {
    return "Bar to string"
}
```

I want to

- convert a `*Foo` type to `Bar`, and
- override it `String()` with my own

However, I found that I can override normal Foo/Bar functions, like `Call()`, but not able to override the `String()` function with my own. Detail code at

https://play.golang.org/p/nzYQzIYlesQ

The actual default behavior that I want to override is --
https://godoc.org/github.com/blevesearch/bleve#SearchResult.String

Is it possible?

Comment: You need a value receiver on `Bar`: `func (b Bar) String() string`.

Comment: Wow, that simple. thx! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: there is no method overriding in Go. You can define a new type embedding another one, and define the same function for the new type. That's what you are doing here:

```
type Bar struct {
    *Foo
}
```

Here, `Bar` is a new type embedding a `*Foo`, thus also getting all the methods defined for `*Foo`. That is not the same thing as all method of `Foo`. Methods defined for `Foo` are defined for both `Foo` and `*Foo`, however methods defined for `*Foo` are only defined for `*Foo` and not for `Foo`.

In your example, `String` is defined for `*Foo` and not for `Foo`.

Similarly, when you define `func (b *Bar) String() string`, that method is defined for `*Bar`, but not for `Bar`.

To make your example work, simply define `String` for `Bar`: `func (b Bar) String() string`.

Comment: Wow, that simple. thx! :) https://play.golang.org/p/U3x8k2VwbJJ